# State verbs and the present continuous

Tags: grammar

I've read in several articles that we don't usually use state verbs with the present continuous

But our Professor said that we do use some of them in the present continuous to emphasise that a situation is temporary or for a period of time around the present

and he gave this example :

> Ella’s with us at the moment. The children are loving having her here

and now I'm confused ..

Comment: Personally, would rephrase as "The children love having her here."